# What am I doing wrong with Glide signature method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

This is what I have:

```
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            String str = "images.jpg";

            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                str = str.substring(0, 6) + i + ".jpg";
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(str);
                File localFile = File.createTempFile("images" + i, "jpg");
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(storageReference).signature(new StringSignature(localFile.length() + "@" + localFile.lastModified())).into(images.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }

    }
});
```

My app crashes when I click on the button.

I basically want to refresh the ImageViews so that when I change an image in Firebase storage, the images would update when I click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Loading from a Firebase `StorageReference` requires use of [FirebaseImageLoader()](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md):

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader()) // <== ADD THIS
    .load(storageReference)
    .signature(new StringSignature(localFile.length() + "@" + localFile.lastModified()))
    .into(images.get(i));
```

You will need this build dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
}
```